# reading from two mono files and converting to one stero wav file- without the ability to use Naudion

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I'm trying to read from two alaw/pcm files in the following way:

```
byte[] dlBuffer = null;

if (dlStream != null)
{
    dlStream.Position = 0;
    dlBuffer = new byte[dlStream.Length+1];
    int readDL = dlStream.Read(dlBuffer, 0, dlBuffer.Length);
}

byte[] ulBuffer = null;  

if (ulStream != null)
{
    ulStream.Position = 0;
    ulBuffer = new byte[ulStream.Length+1];
    int readUL = ulStream.Read(ulBuffer, 0, ulBuffer.Length);
}
```

And then to save the buffers to one wav file:

```
private const int WAVE_HEADER_SIZE = 44;
private const int WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;  // = 2,097,152
private bool SaveBufferToWave(string wavFileName, VoiceMetadata metadata,byte[] dlBuffer,byte[] ulBuffer)
{
    if ((wavFileName == null) || (wavFileName.Length == 0) || (metadata == null))
        return false;

    FileStream fileStream = null;
    bool success = true;

    try
    {
        byte[] waveBuffer = new byte[WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesToWrite = 0;
        int dlRead = 0, ulRead = 0;
        //If we have DL & UL write stereo wav, else write mono wave
        int channels = (metadata.DLExists && metadata.ULExists) ? 2 : 1;
        int samples = (int)metadata.TotalTimeMS * (VoiceMetadata.SAMPLES_PER_SECOND / 1000);

        fileStream = new FileStream(wavFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        BinaryWriter wrt = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);

        wrt.Write(GetHeader(
                    WAVE_HEADER_SIZE + (samples) * (channels) * sizeof(short), sizeof(short) * 8,
                    channels,
                    8000));

        if (channels == 2)
        {
            if (dlRead == 0)
            {
                dlRead = dlBuffer.Length;
            }

            if (ulRead == 0)
            {
                ulRead = ulBuffer.Length;
            }

            if ((dlRead != 0) && (ulRead != 0))
            {
                //Create the stero wave buffer
                Array.Clear(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < dlRead / 2; ++i)
                {
                    waveBuffer[i * 4 + 0] = dlBuffer[i * 2];
                    waveBuffer[i * 4 + 1] = dlBuffer[i * 2 + 1];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < ulRead / 2; ++i)
                {
                    waveBuffer[i * 4 + 2] = ulBuffer[i * 2];
                    waveBuffer[i * 4 + 3] = ulBuffer[i * 2 + 1];
                }

                bytesToWrite = Math.Max(ulRead * 2, dlRead * 2);
                dlRead = 0;
                ulRead = 0;
            }
            else
                bytesToWrite = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create the mono wave buffer
            if (metadata.ULExists)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(ulBuffer, 0, waveBuffer, 0, ulBuffer.Length);
                bytesToWrite = ulBuffer.Length;
            }
            else if (metadata.DLExists)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(dlBuffer, 0, waveBuffer, 0, dlBuffer.Length);
                bytesToWrite = dlBuffer.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                bytesToWrite = 0;
            }
        }

        if (bytesToWrite > 0)
            fileStream.Write(waveBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite);

        Logger.Debug("File {0} was saved successfully in wav format.", wavFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error("Failed saving file {0} in wav format, Exception: {1}.", wavFileName, e);
        success = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Close();
    }

    return success;
}
```

Most of the times it works fine, but sometimes I get one of this two exceptions:

Failed saving file c:\Samples\WAV\24112014-095948.283.wav in wav format, Exception: System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Failed saving file c:\Samples\WAV\24112014-100742.409.wav in wav format, Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

What can be the problem?

Comment: **Where** do you get those exceptions?

Comment: When saving the buffer

Comment: *Exactly* where (at which lines) in your code do you get the exceptions?

Comment: Buffer.BlockCopy(dlBuffer, 0, waveBuffer, 0, dlBuffer.Length);

System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.